# i want to use same 6 slider in my site

Tags: javascript, html, css

. I have a slider with Thumbnails , I want to use 6 same slider in my site .(3 slider in 1 line break another 3 slider in one line )when i copy paste html its not working.only first 1 is working

```
 <script>`
function changeImage(event) {`
event = event || window.event;
var targetElement = event.target || event.srcelement;
if (targetElement.tagName == "IMG") {
document.getElementById("mainImage").src = targetElement.getAttribute("src");
   }
}
</script>
```

html

```
<img height="250" width="500" style="border:3px solid grey" src="images/g1.jpg" id="mainImage" />
<br />

<div id="imgstyle" onclick="changeImage(event)">
<image class="imgstyle" src="images/g1.jpg" />
<image class="imgstyle" src="images/g2.jpg" />
<image class="imgstyle" src="images/g3.jpg" />
 <image class="imgstyle" src="images/g4.jpg" />
 <image class="imgstyle" src="images/g5.jpg" />
</div>
```

css

```
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
.imgstyle {
display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
}

.imgstyle + .imgstyle {
  border-left: 1px solid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure your question would benefit from rephrasing as it is currently quite hard to understand what you are trying to accomplish. Regardless, if I understood correctly and you want to have two rows of thumbnail images instead of one, here is my suggestion.

Since you are using `float` on the thumbnail images, you need to clear the float to force images onto a new line. This is done easiest with `clear: both`. You will need one of two things:

**A CSS rule** to cut off at the *nth* image. Use this if you want all rows to have the same number of images.

```
.imgstyle:nth-of-type(3n + 1) {
  clear: both;
}
```

The `nth-of-type(3n+1)`selector will apply to the first, fourth, seventh, etc. element and clear the float attribute preceding it. This forces the following content to start on a new line.

[CSS rule Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BwRWJq)

**An HTML element** to manually cut off where you want to. By adding the following element between your image HTML code you can specify exactly where your line breaks will be.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="break"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.break {
  clear: both;
}
```

Again, if this was not the question you wanted an answer to, I suggest rephrasing your question for better clarity.

Comment: No I don't want two thumbnail.i want same slider in opposite site.it means first 1 is left side another in right side.

Comment: Could you come up with an image to clarify what you want? Unfortunately I'm finding your description hard to understand.

Comment: i add a pic what i want exactly . can u help me